# How to add validation to the RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

Im using RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor to get the date occurence.I want to add validation to the control.Could you guys please help me add validation to this?

```
<telerik:RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor  runat="server"  Enabled="true"  ID="Eventdaterecurrence"></telerik:RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor>
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

**One approach** is to apply the desired logic in the server-side events before inserting or updating appointments (e.g., the Button.Click event where you consume the rules).

- Here is one example that shows similar logic used with RadScheduler: https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/details/how-to-validate-that-recurring-appointment-s-occurrences-doesn-t-overlap-(ms-outlook-doesn-t-allow-such-appointment-s-scheduling).

**Another approach** is to use JS to hook to the necessary click events and access the controls you want to validate so you can perform your logic: https://www.telerik.com/forums/validation-and-default-selection-of-radschedulerrecurrenceeditor.

- Note that you should still apply server validation.

A **third option** you can look into is adding a Validator control during server rendering (the PreRender or the OnLoad event for example), and use similar logic to this example: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/scheduler/customizing-the-advanced-form/handling-formcreated#add-a-new-custom-validator-for-the-description-field.

- You would need to review the control tree and traverse it to get the desired controls, and you should still implement server validation.